# Issue with homepage while deploying create react app

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

How can one deploy a create react app to gh-pages?

My packages.json folder has my homepage listed exactly as this: "homepage": "https://mgcraig78.github.io/RoboFriends",

However, the app will not deploy to gh-pages, and when I enter `npm run build`, the terminal tells me this (which I'm assuming is the issue, but I can't figure out how to fix it): The project was built assuming it is hosted at /RoboFriends/.   <- this obviously is not the homepage I have entered into my packages.json file.

Comment: Just curious, did you follow the deployment guide for gh-pages here? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/, if  thats the case, could you please share your package.json file?

Comment: @polcats yes I did run through the react deployment steps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/RoboFriends` from your `homepage` link in package.json to:

```
"homepage": "https://mgcraig78.github.io"
```

Then run

```
npm run build
```

What you deploy to github is what's inside the `build` folder that contains `index.html`

Comment: @Matthew please try this one out. I am also curious about what happened in your case. I hope this solves your problem

Comment: Hello Thank you.  Indeed I have my homepage listed in my packages.json file exactly as you have described above, but when I run build, only /RoboFriends is recorded and applied to the build folder.  Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Could you also share your folder structure?

Comment: Hey, sorry i just fixed the links that i meant. I meant remove the `/RoboFriends` from your homepage link then try to rebuild. You don't have to put subfolder in your case

Comment: So I did as Robert suggests and the resulting line from the terminal is this: "The project was built assuming it is hosted at /" Yikes.

Comment: ^^^^^ Yikes is my addition btw

Comment: Yes that means that your project is hosted at root. So if you deploy the content of `build` folder on your gh page then it should work

Comment: @RobertTirta --- So I figured out what the problem is.  Not sure how common this problem might be, but I'm in the habit of calling my git remotes "mc" after doing a lot of pair programming where initials of participants are important.  I found that if you go to deploy a react app without a git remote not named "origin", it won't publish.  All my syntax was correct in the project and everything was setup properly, except this detail.  I created a remote named "origin" and it published.  Unfortunately it's broken, but a small victory, at least it published!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it helps! Please accept the answer if it helps you in your case @MatthewCraig